# How to get rid of all the links using feature?

Tags: php

I have the function of reducing the links of one of the services:

```
function Shorten($url){
$api_url="https://server/api?api=key&url=".$url."&format=text";
$res= @file_get_contents($api_url);
  if($res){
    return $res;
  }}
```

And I have the html code of the letter that sends my server:

```
Hey! Go in <a href="http://google.com">Google</a> or <a href="http://yahoo.com">Yahoo</a>
```

I need to replace the links with a function, that is, reduce them on the server. But I can't substitute a value in `preg_replace`.

Answer (score 0):

You are looking for [preg_replace_callback](http://php.net/manual/en/function.preg-replace-callback.php). The key will be to get the right regular expression to match all the URLs you want to replace, Ex:

```
preg_replace_callback("@https?://[\w\./]@", 'Shorten', $content)
```